# Редирект пользователя на определенный aciton Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Нужно настроить редирект пользователя на определенный action. action на который происходит редирект зависит от того какие данные он ввел. Вопрос как это лучше всего сделать? Я сделал таким образом. но способ получился громоздким, потому что нужно будет добавлять такую проверку в каждый action.

```
public function actionIndex(){
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    $model = new SignupForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->signup()) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', '');
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    return $this->render('index', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
} elseif (!Step1::getByUser(User::findIdentity(Yii::$app->user->id))) {
    return $this->redirect('step1');
} elseif (!Step2::getByUser(User::findIdentity(Yii::$app->user->id))) {
    return $this->redirect('step2');
} else {
    return $this->redirect('step3');
}
```

}

Есть ли более подходящий способ ?

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас не более 3-х шагов - пойдет и так. Для большего кол-ва наверное можно сделать как-то так...

```php
$maxStep = 3;
$exists = false;
for( $step = 1; $step < $maxStep; $step++) {
    $model = 'Step'.$step;
    $exists = $$model::getByUser(User::findIdentity(Yii::$app->user->id));
    if ( $exists ) { break; }
}
$this->reidrect( 'step'.( $exists ? $step : $maxStep ) );
```